# How to interpret cross correlation output?

Tags: signal-analysis, cross-correlation

The output of cross corelation shows the similarity between the two signals. But in what respect is there a similarity? I didn't quite understand how I should interpret the output. How should I interpret the output? I'm really trying to make sense of the underlying logic and output here rather than the math statement. I am also sharing example MATLAB code.

```
N=1024; % Number of samples to generate
f1=1; % Frequency of the sinewave
FS=200; % Sampling frequency
n=0:N-1; % Sampling index
x=sin(2*pi*f1*n/FS); % Generate x(n)
y=x+randn(1,N); % Generate y(n)
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(x);
title('Pure Sinewave');
grid;
subplot(3,1,2);
plot(y);
title('y(n), Pure Sinewave + Noise');
grid;
Rxy=xcorr(x,y); % Estimate the cross correlation
subplot(3,1,3);
plot(Rxy);
title('Cross correlation Rxy');
grid;
```

Here is the output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross correlation computes the "correlation" (a measure of similarity) between two signals *at different offsets (called lags) from each other.* You can think of one signal being slid along the other and being multiplied and summed with it at each lag.

In your case you have a signal $x$ that you believe exists with in another signal $y$. The cross correlation between them will be maximum at the time delay (lag) where $x$ lines up with itself in $y$. In your case this appears to happen a little after the 1000th lag (which corresponds to a delay of zero). This allows you to find where $x$ exists within $y$. This is the principle behind [matched filtering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter).

This is easier to see if you make use of the `lags` output from MATLAB's xcorr: `[Rxy, lags] = xcorr(x, y); figure; plot(lags, Rxy)`. Also, MATLAB's default cross correlation calculation does not normalize for the magnitudes of the signals. You can make it normalize to between -1 and 1 by using the "coeff" parameter: `[Rxy, lags] = xcorr(x, y, 'coeff')`. This is equivalent to `xcorr(x, y)./sqrt(sum(x.^2)*sum(y.^2))`. See [this link for more](https://This%20allows%20you%20to%20find%20where%20%7B485941ab-77f2-4af2-a4d7-b012bbbd3c43%7D%20exists%20within%20%7Bb5cfc23c-68f6-4e0d-997f-81c9ce6a5966%7D.%20This%20is%20the%20principle%20behind%20%5Bmatched%20filtering%5D%5B1%5D.).

[image]

Now, you see that the maximum similarity between the signals is a little more than 0.5 on a scale of -1 to 1. This is because a lot of the energy in $y$ is noise, and $x$ and $y$ don't have the same energy. If the signals were identical with the same energy ($y = x$), the normalized correlation would be 1. If $y = -x$, the normalized correlation would be -1.

Now the reason your cross correlation looks cyclical is because $x$ is periodic, so at different lags it partially correlates with $y$. When they are perfectly aligned on top of each other the correlation is maximum. Then as $x$ begins to slide past $y$, the correlation decreases.

Comment: You are right in what you wrote, but how can I understand the similarity from the signal in the graph. Could you please interpret the cross-correlated graph by explaining how the similarity was examined in depth? @Gillipse

Comment: I edited the post. Let me know if you have more questions!

Comment: Great explanation! Also thanks for adding the code to the explanation. Finally, does cross-correlation just say a ratio for similarity? Or can we plot the signal that looks like both signals here?

Comment: Glad it helped. Yes, cross-correlation basically just gives a measure of similarity at different delays. It doesn't calculate any kind of basis function.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply. Opened my mind! @Gillespie